# initialize an empty dictionary in an empty dictionary - Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, dictionary

I want to pass a variable (dict) to server with php code. The variable is a dictionary inside a dictionary and inside a dictionary.

In Swift and Java, I can do write it that way

Swift: `var pageDict = [String: [String: [String: Int]]]()`

Java: `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> pageDict = new HashMap<>();`

EDIT

If I initialize the dict something like this in Javascript `[[[]]]` , I receive this error

```
<b>Warning</b>:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in <b>test.php</b> on line <b>166</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in <b>test.php</b> on line <b>166</b><br />
<br />
```

In line 166 (Server Code)

```
line165 function getExistData($pageDict, $location) {
line166     return in_array($location, array_keys($pageDict)) ? $pageDict[$location] : array();
line167 }
```

If I try to do it that way, `var pageDict = {"____": {"____": {"____": 1}}};` everything works prefect. But this definitely is not a prefect way to do it

Wondering how can I do it in Javascript?

Comment: Serialize an object or array into a string with `JSON.stringify`, and send that string as data. Nested objects/arrays make no difference

Comment: If an empty dictionary inside an empty dictionary, can you give me a hint?

Comment: Still makes no difference. Also, `dictionary` has no meaning in Javascript, you're thinking of `object`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following structure to store 3 level multimap.

```
var mapLevel1 = new Object(); // innermost map
mapLevel1[String1] = Int1;
mapLevel1[String2] = Int2;

var mapLevel2 = new Object(); 
mapLevel2[String3] = map1;

var mapLevel3 = new Object(); //outermost map
mapLevel3[String3] = map2;
```

Edit: As suggested by @CertainPerformance, convert to string using `JSON.stringify` before passing data to server.

Comment: but I dont know the key and value before I pass it to server

Comment: So are you gonna send empty structure to server?

Comment: Thats because your ```$pageDict``` is a string, whereas ```array_keys``` expects an array. You'll have to convert it to an PHP array.

Comment: If I try to trick the code and do it like this ```var pageDict = {"____": {"____": {"____": 1}}};``` everything works prefect. But this definitely is not a prefect way to do it.

Comment: Because ```"[[[]]]".toString()``` returns empty string. Hence the value passed to server is not ```[[[]]]```, but null. Make it as object and use ```JSON.stringify``` before passing to server..